# Integrate ActionScript 3 dropdown menu with HTML/Javasscript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a video recording application using ActionScript 3.0.

For that, I've used AS3 dropdown menus to allow the user to choose camera and microphone for recording. For example, the following code gets the list of microphones.

```
var Mics:Array = Microphone.names;
var micData:Array = new Array();
for(i = 0; i < Mics.length; i++) {
    //camMicData.availableMicrophones.addItem({label:Mics[i], data:i});
    micData.push( {label:Mics[i], data:i} );
}
```

Then, the following code initialises a dropdown menu:

```
cbMicSelection = new ComboBox();
cbMicSelection.dataProvider = new DataProvider(micData);
cbMicSelection.dropdownWidth = 175;
cbMicSelection.width = 175;
cbMicSelection.move(340, 250);
addChild(cbMicSelection);
```

Then

```
activeMic = Microphone.getMicrophone( int( cbMicSelection.selectedItem.data ) );
```

selects the mic.

Now I need the dropdown menu to be HTML/JS instead of AS3.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Questions without evidence of your own attempt are generally received very poorly. Have you tried anything so far? Do you have experience with HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah, I do have experience with both, and I've seen several tutorials of calling AS functions through JS - which I've implemented myself. But I can't seem to find any resources to get something of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `ExternalInterface`, that will let you trigger javascript from your actionscript and vice versa: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Here is a slideshare showing some of the strategies for communicating between the two: http://www.slideshare.net/BeautifulInterfaces/connecting-flash-and-javascript-using-externalinterface-2452543

Hth,
Aaron

Comment: I've seen the Adobe reference earlier.

thanks for the slideshare link. I'll check it out.

Comment: Here's a working example also to help you get started: http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/08/javascript-for-flashers-externalinterface/